# storybook shows 'This story is not configured to handle controls. ' error

Tags: storybook

I installed storybook by using `npx tsdx create` 
and selected `react-with-storybook` to make style component library.
while developing, I got 'This story is not configured to handle controls. ' error.
tsdx automatically installs all the essential addons include storybook controls.

 So there's no reason to get this error.

After searching about this, I found [this](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11769) post.
Long story short, This error is about storybook dependency version.
They said, If I downgrade version under 6.0.9, it would works find.
So I tried, and this time I couldn't even start the project. (build failed or something).

This is my devDependencies from `package.json`

```json
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.2",
    "@size-limit/preset-small-lib": "^7.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-is": "^17.0.2",
    "size-limit": "^7.0.8",
    "tsdx": "^0.14.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
```

and What I changed were

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.2",
    "@size-limit/preset-small-lib": "^7.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.0.9", <<=
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.0.9", <<=
    "@storybook/addons": "6.0.9", <<=
    "@storybook/react": "6.0.9", <<=
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-is": "^17.0.2",
    "size-limit": "^7.0.8",
    "tsdx": "^0.14.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
```

If you know any workaround, please share! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case this error was caused from another story, which had a `control` that had incorrect options, here is the web component

```
export default {
  title: 'Buttons/HTMLButton',
  argTypes: {
    sizeClass: {
      control: { type: 'select' },
      options: { '': '', Huge: 'huge-size' }
    },
  },
};
```

As soon as I fixed the `options` to `{ 'Default': '', Huge: 'huge-size' }` it fixed this issue.

Even though this story was completely different, but it was causing controls to disappear in a different story, at the same time the controls are available and working in the `Docs` tab, but in the main Canvas you will see no controls and with error `This story is not configured to handle controls.`.

To debug this issue, I had to move all stories to a different location, bring back stories one-by-one to see which is causing the problem.

Not too often but sometimes I have faced this funny behaviour of storybook, where an issue will lead to a completely different and misleading error.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible cause of this error which had me scratching my head for some time, is that your story render function *MUST* take an argument, even if you don't use it:

```
export const MyStory = () => <SomeComponent/>; // ❌ Won't work

export const MyStory = (whatever) => <SomeComponent/>; // ✅ Works
```